# Loop in nodejs xmlbuilder

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-builder

How can I loop through and choose some data from the array?
I try to manage it, but inside the loop the xmlbuilder did not define the expected result. To choose the right value maybe it is easy just I have to define the exact element but not yet tested,

Expected result:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<export>
  <sor>
    <ragszam>PBPU8393290190011113017025</ragszam>
    <ugyfeladat1>10093-669800</ugyfeladat1>
  </sor>
  <sor>
    <ragszam>PBPU83932901903213117025</ragszam>
    <ugyfeladat1>10093-885200</ugyfeladat1>
  </sor>
  <sor>
    <ragszam>PBPU83616165165113017025</ragszam>
    <ugyfeladat1>10093-998700</ugyfeladat1>
  </sor>
</export>``` 

My Code:



var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var array = [
  {
    'CsoportID': 'CLG22030934458',
    'Shipment ID': 'PBPU8393290190011113017025',
    'Requested': '2022-03-09 11:17:05',
    'Status': 'Folyamatban',
    'Futár felvette': '2022-03-09 17:27:47',
    'Követőkód': '10093-669800'
  },
  {
    'CsoportID': 'CLG22030934458',
    'Shipment ID': 'PBPU83932901903213117025',
    'Requested': '2022-03-09 11:17:05',
    'Status': 'Folyamatban',
    'Futár felvette': '2022-03-09 17:27:47',
    'Követőkód': '10093-885200'
  },
  {
    'CsoportID': 'CLG22030934458',
    'Shipment ID': 'PBPU83616165165113017025',
    'Requested': '2022-03-09 11:17:05',
    'Status': 'Folyamatban',
    'Futár felvette': '2022-03-09 17:27:47',
    'Követőkód': '10093-998700'
  }
]


for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  var feed = builder.create('export', { encoding: 'utf-8' })
    .ele('sor')
      .ele('ragszam', array[i][1]).up()
      .ele('ugyfeladat1', array[i][5]).up()
      .up()
  }

console.log(feed.end({ pretty: true }));
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the root element outside the loop and add new child elements to it in the loop, also access desired object properties by their name, not index

try this:

```
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var array = [
  {
    'CsoportID': 'CLG22030934458',
    'Shipment ID': 'PBPU8393290190011113017025',
    'Requested': '2022-03-09 11:17:05',
    'Status': 'Folyamatban',
    'Futár felvette': '2022-03-09 17:27:47',
    'Követőkód': '10093-669800'
  },
  {
    'CsoportID': 'CLG22030934458',
    'Shipment ID': 'PBPU83932901903213117025',
    'Requested': '2022-03-09 11:17:05',
    'Status': 'Folyamatban',
    'Futár felvette': '2022-03-09 17:27:47',
    'Követőkód': '10093-885200'
  },
  {
    'CsoportID': 'CLG22030934458',
    'Shipment ID': 'PBPU83616165165113017025',
    'Requested': '2022-03-09 11:17:05',
    'Status': 'Folyamatban',
    'Futár felvette': '2022-03-09 17:27:47',
    'Követőkód': '10093-998700'
  }
]


var feed = builder.create('export', { encoding: 'utf-8' })

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    feed.ele('sor')
      .ele('ragszam', array[i]['Shipment ID']).up()
      .ele('ugyfeladat1', array[i]['Követőkód']).up()
      .up()
  }

console.log(feed.end({ pretty: true }));
```